# Different Docker 1.9 networks talk to each other?

Tags: networking, docker

I want to create two Docker 1.9 networks. Network A runs a web server, an application server, and a Postgres server (all containers). Network B runs a SMTP server and other containers. I need containers on Network A to get to Network B. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [libnetwork implementation](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/docs/design.md#implementations) includes an overlay mode:

> The overlay driver implements networking that can span multiple hosts using overlay network encapsulations such as VXLAN. For more details on its design, please see the [Overlay Driver Design](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/docs/overlay.md).
>
> The new native overlay network driver supports multi-host networking natively out-of-the-box.
>   This support is accomplished with the help of libnetwork, a built-in VXLAN-based overlay network driver, and Docker's libkv library.

**[This tutorial](https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/blob/master/6-networking.md)** explains how to make containers talk to each other even if they are on different machines, provided they are registered to the same overlay network.

That will involve setting up first a K/V (Key/Value) store:

[image: https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/raw/master/images/tut6-step1.png]

> Now that your three nodes are configured to use the key-value store, you can create an overlay network on any node. When you create the network, it is distributed to all the nodes.
>
> When you create your first overlay network on any host, Docker also creates another network on each host called `docker_gwbridge`. Docker uses this network to provide external access for containers.
>
> Every container in an overlay network also gets an `eth` interface in the `docker_gwbridge` which allows the container to access the external world.
>   The `docker_gwbridge` is similar to Docker's default `bridge` network, but unlike the `bridge` it restricts Inter-Container Communication(ICC).
>   Docker creates only one `docker_gwbridge` bridge network per host regardless of the number of overlay networks present.
>
> Docker added an entry to `/etc/hosts` for each container that belongs to the RED overlay network.
>   Therefore, to reach `container2` from `container1`, you can simply use its name. Docker automatically updates `/etc/hosts` when containers connect and disconnect from an overlay network.

[image: https://github.com/docker/dceu_tutorials/raw/master/images/tut6-step6.png]

> At this point, `container2` and `container3` can communicate over the `RED` overlay network.
>   They are both on the same `docker_gwbridge` but they cannot communicate using that bridge network without host-port mapping. The `docker_gwbridge` is used for all other traffic.