# Docker 1.9 overlay network - access from host

Tags: networking, docker, containers

Im curious to know what the best method would be to access containers on a Docker overlay network, from the host machine that's running the daemon.

I previously used Weave, and would expose a weave IP to the host machine, so that utilities running on the host machine can access containers on the Weave IP address space.

Id like to be able to address containers using their overlay assigned IP address, from the host machine (not from within the containers themselves).

One way would be to expose ports on the containers themselves, but Id like to access them via paths that the container expects when running in its production network.

new:
I figured out that I can access containers over the docker_gwbridge, who's IP is 172.18.0.1. So if the container overlay network IP is 10.0.0.10 then it can be accessed from host on the IP 172.18.0.10
Is this the best way to address containers?

helpful:
[Different Docker 1.9 networks talk to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967258/different-docker-1-9-networks-talk-to-each-other/33969637#33969637)

Comment: Did you consider to _not_ try to access containers from the host, but from another container, which is connected to the network? That container might be temporary by using the `--rm` option.

Comment: thats one way of doing it...  
I ended up doing something along those lines, doing all communication on the overlay network via containers themselves using that network, by 'docker exec'-ing...